# simple js slider, read of ofssetX make handler jumpy

Tags: javascript, slider

I am trying to build very simple horizontal slider using pure javascript, i dont want any libraries like jquery. Task seemed easy at the beginning but i have encountered a problem. I am trying to get readings from `offsetX` property to set handler in correct place. The problem is that when i am sliding handler on the track it sometimes switches event target and changes readings from handler to track to slider container. This entire process visual effect is not the best.

this is how i constructed this:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="track">
        <div class="handler"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the code behind:

```
var dragging = false;

document.querySelector('.slider').onmousemove = function(event) {
    if(dragging) {
        document.querySelector('.handler').style.left = (event.offsetX - 15) + 'px';
    }
};

document.querySelector('.handler').onmousedown = function(event) {
    dragging = true;
};

window.onmouseup = function(event) {
    dragging = false;
}
```

[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qz8ym95h/3/)

I think that solution would be to prevent event from false readings (from handler or track) and always use only mouse position relative to slider div. But how to do that i dont know yet. Does anyone? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct, because `event.offsetX` is relative to original event target you get different values from handler, track and slider. You could instead calculate offset based on slider and mouse positions relative to client window. Take a look at attached code snippet.

```js
var dragging = false;
var sliderEl = document.querySelector('.slider');
var handlerEl = document.querySelector('.handler');

sliderEl.onmousemove = function(event) {
  if (dragging) {
    var sliderRect = sliderEl.getBoundingClientRect();
    var offset = Math.max(event.clientX - sliderRect.left, 0);
    offset = Math.min(offset, sliderRect.width);
    handlerEl.style.left = (offset - 15) + 'px';
  }
  return false;
};

handlerEl.onmousedown = function(event) {
  dragging = true;
};

window.onmouseup = function(event) {
  dragging = false;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.slider,
.slider * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slider {
  background: #ccc;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.slider .track {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
}
.slider .track .handler {
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: lime;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 15px);
  left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="slider">
    <div class="track">
      <div class="handler"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That is what i was looking for sir ;) Thank You for the help ;)